# How to select from an option in a navbar that is written as a <div>

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I am making a web scraper with selenium C# and ran into an issue.
I am using a website called Taver.Ai
But basically, I ran into an issue with the following HTML code:
[**HTML CODE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECjVR.png).
I get an error when trying to post code idk why!?
In the html page, when you click on the navbar icon on the top right, a list of character appear and you can click on each div to choose to chat with a certain character.
However, when using selenium I get the following error:
[**error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPZDo.png).
Here is what my code looks like
I GET THE FORMAT ERROR
[**I am literally crying**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdzN8.png)

```
    <div id="rm_print_charaters_block">
        <div class="character_select" chid="5"></div>
        <div class="character_select" chid="4"></div>
        <div class="character_select" chid="3"></div>
        <div class="character_select" chid="2"></div>
        <div class="character_select" chid="1"></div>
        <div class="character_select" chid="0"></div>
    </div>
```

And here are some pics of the website:

- [**starting screen**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhZB9.jpg)
- [**navbar**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvYRh.jpg)
- [**character selected**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot2NX.png)

The program's main goal is to allow me to chat with ai using my terminal.

Thanks to anyone who tries to help me <3

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using NUnit.Framework;


namespace Se
{
    class progrma
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            // Test name: tavern
            // Step # | name | target | value
            // 1 | open | https://whole-guests-say-35-198-247-4.loca.lt/ | 
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://whole-guests-say-35-198-247-4.loca.lt/");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            // 2 | setWindowSize | 1288x1399 | 
            driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1288, 1399);
            // 3 | click | css=.nav-toggle | 
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".nav-toggle")).Click();
            // 4 | click | css=.character_select:nth-child(3) > .ch_name | 
            //driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".character_select:nth-child(3) > .ch_name")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@chid=\"5\"]")).Click();
            // 5 | click | id=send_textarea | 
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("send_textarea")).Click();

            driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".mes:nth-child(65) p")).Click();
            // 9 | click | id=send_textarea | 
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("send_textarea")).Click();
            // 10 | type | id=send_textarea | it sounds amazing, let's go
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("send_textarea")).SendKeys("it sounds amazing, let\'s go");
            // 13 | click | id=send_but | 
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("send_but")).Click();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to just make it so it hovers over the element and then clicks it.
here is what I did.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@chid=\"6\"]"))).Click().Perform();
```

and this is the full code now!

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using NUnit.Framework;


namespace Se
{
    class progrma
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            // Test name: tavern
            // Step # | name | target | value
            // 1 | open | https://free-suits-flow-34-142-136-235.loca.lt/ | 
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://free-suits-flow-34-142-136-235.loca.lt/");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            // 2 | setWindowSize | 1288x1399 | 
            driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1288, 1399);
            // 3 | click | css=.nav-toggle | 
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".nav-toggle")).Click();
            // 4 | click | css=.character_select:nth-child(3) > .ch_name | 
            //driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".character_select:nth-child(3) > .ch_name")).Click();

            action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@chid=\"6\"]"))).Click().Perform();
            
            
            //driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@chid=\"6\"]")).Click();
            // 5 | click | id=send_textarea | 
            
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("send_textarea")).Click();

            driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".mes:nth-child(65) p")).Click();
            // 9 | click | id=send_textarea | 
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("send_textarea")).Click();
            // 10 | type | id=send_textarea | it sounds amazing, let's go
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("send_textarea")).SendKeys("it sounds amazing, let\'s go");
            // 13 | click | id=send_but | 
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("send_but")).Click();
        }
    }
}
```